# Why isn't the identity/unit matrix upright?

Tags: matrices, notation

I realize this is more of a typesetting problem then a mathematical one. I've already tried the TeX stack exchange and the question got canned.

In ISO 80000-2:2009, variables and running numbers are italicised while mathematically defined constants and contextual independents are to be upright. However, it advises that the identity matrix is either the italic ***E*** or ***I***. (Either is boldface to indicate it is a matrix/vector/tensor)

Given a fixed matrix size, the identity isn't contextually dependent, and it's certainly constant. You can even define it purely in terms of the Kronecker delta, which is, according to the standard, set upright. So, if I were using tensor-notation, it would be upright in the form of the Kronecker! But the matrix notation equivalent is italic. This doesn't make sense to me.

**Edit:**
I seem to have kicked up a bit of dander, even somehow earning a downvote. Please note that I'm not advocating an ideology here. I take notation very seriously and I like to consult conventional wisdom before landing on something I like. This particular inconsistency made me curious and I thought that the broader wisdom of this community may enlighten me.

Comment: You should ask the ISO committee that decided on that.

Comment: Perhaps the ISO committee should have asked you.

Comment: @hardmath Why the sarchasm? It's an honest question that doesn't have a clear answer. I came here because of the diversity of experience in this community, hoping someone may have insight that I don't.

Comment: How does it propose to denote operators and/or functions?  Perhaps it is based on the interpretation of the identity as an operator that took precedent.  I do not have access to the article (the source I found on iso.org would require payment), but does it *really* matter what it says?  So long as your reader understands your notation (*be it based on context, or on an international standard*), that is all one would hope for, right?

Comment: My point is that the gospel of an International Standards Organization can often be improved by those for whom the standards are promulgated.  In the mathematical tradition authors are free to use the notation best suited to the purpose of exposition, provided definitions are provided for anything unconventional.  ISO standards tend to favor engineering practices rather than purely scientific ones, so my "sarcasm" is really to encourage you to write like a mathematician and choose the notational convention you think best.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That's a good idea, but I'm not sure who was on the committee. I wouldn't have been surprised if someone in this community was in fact on the committee. And, this way it is public. I know I'm not the first to point this out as I've found the same concern in books on typesetting.

Comment: @hardmath Correct me if I'm mistaken, but it reads like you have an ideological bent that you're taking out on me. I have nothing against inventing notations, I like looking at conventional wisdom before making decisions. Notation is something I take very seriously.

Comment: I applaud your thoughtful choice of notation, and hope nothing I've said struck a discouraging note.  You've not really given the context in which you are choosing notation (a textbook, a lecture note, an operator guide/user manual).  If you use $I$ or $E$ and make it clear by context that the matrix is the identity, your Readers will surely be able to follow.

Comment: @JMoravitz The content of the standard doesn't matter so much, since I will take the notation that makes sense to me. But I like to consult conventional wisdom before making decisions, and I find that particular ISO standard has proven useful as a reference. If there is a good reason that they violate their own convention for this particular case, I am curious to know what it is.

Comment: Thanks, @hardmath. I appreciate the encouraging note.

Comment: The full title of ISO 80000-2 is [Quantities and units — Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2).  It doesn't signify to me that these guidelines were intended to be binding or normative for mathematical exposition per se.

Comment: I don't think I know even **one** mathematician Who is aware the standard even exists, let alone if it prescribes a slanted I for the identity mateix, and I am sure no one I know cares.